# How to read a file of mp3 files line by line and output the longest ones?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file that I am reading that contains mp3 files.

```
file1.mp3
file2.mp3
etc
```

I would like to read this file line by line and then print out in an order that is highest to lowest.

So far I have

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    duration=$(ffprobe "./AUDIO/$file.mp3" 2>&1 | awk '/Duration/ { print $2 }')
    echo -e $duration"\t"$file
done | sort -n < in_file.txt
```

This doesn't output in the specified format that I want it to and doesn't ffprobe, why?

Comment: If you want to use the `sort` for sorting according to _duration_, you first need to create a (temporary) file which holds the durations **and** the file names. Then sort this file on the duration field, and finally drop the duration field. This approach is called a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input file should be redirected into the loop rather than the `sort` command.

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    duration=$(ffprobe "./AUDIO/$file.mp3" 2>&1 | awk '/Duration/ { print $2 }')
    echo -e $duration"\t"$file
done < in_file.txt | sort -n
```

Comment: hmm using this is not doing anything

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh I see, silly me, that was the problem. I removed the ```sort -n``` but now it doesn't output from highest to lowest. It just prints the times.

Comment: You could also do `awk '/Duration/ { print $2 }' | tr -d ':.'` to remove the `:` and `.` in the duration